# What conditions must be met for system files to be copied along with a parent folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hidden-file

When browsing folders via Windows Explorer and when the displaying of hidden/system files/folders has been enabled, it's common to find system files that automatically get copied with the parent folder (desktop.ini is a good example of this). What isn't immediately obvious, however, is what triggers this file to be copied with its parent folder. As an example - if only a single file is selected from the parent folder and copied to a different destination, does Windows Explorer presume that any system files in the directory should be copied along with the folder - or are these files only copied if the entire parent directory is selected and moved somewhere else?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: If you copy files, the files are copied. If you copy a folder, all of it is copied (that you have permission). No special cases.

Comment: If a single file is copied, the single file is copied, no other file is copied.  If you want a system file, you would have to copy that system file, to another location.  Of course Windows automatically discovers system files, so it's unnecessary, to copy system files to other locations.  You actually introduce the potential to load the incorrect version of a system file.